# Display mysql Table without knowing total number of cols in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to display mysql table columns without specifying column names in code and I also don't know total number of columns in the table.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test_table");
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $item){
        echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

But output is as follows:

[image]

i.e values are repeating for each col. Please help me out.

Comment: I think you're looking for `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches both an associative array AND a numeric array. Try using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

Alternatively, you can specify a parameter in `mysqli_fetch_array`, like so:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

Or

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

To

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
```